# Get element fron table based on another element

Tags: jquery

How can I get from this code get the phone number (second `<td>`) based on the `img src` picto_telephone.jpg ?

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><img src="picto_telephone.jpg" alt="" border="0"></td>
  <td valign="top">514 767-1855</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><img src="picto_fax.jpg" alt="" border="0"></td>
  <td valign="top">514 999-6524</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `var ph = $('img[src="picto_telephone.jpg"]').parent().next().text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().next().text()
```

Answer (score 0):

another option: `$('img[src="picto_telephone.jpg"]').closest('td').next().text();`